# Dynamicaly add buttons to asp table cell without deleting the cells text

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an asp.table where all the cells contains text and the following function to add buttons to the cells

```
  Button btnactiv = new Button();
                    btnactiv.ID = y.ToString();
                    btnactiv.Text = "Dept " + dr_depts["code_dept"].ToString() + "(" + nbr + " )";
                    cell.Controls.Add(btnactiv);
```

the buttons are added and it works fine but the text of cells gets deleted after i add the buttons how can i add butoons and keep the text please ?

Comment: You can show the same text on buttons ?

Comment: nope the text are dates and a cell can contain many buttons i need the date to be shown in every cell above the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first dynamically create a table cell and then add your text and button to it:

```
 TableCell commentCell = new TableCell();
 Label lblComment = new Label();
 lblComment.Text = "Text to remain in the cell."
 commentCell.Controls.Add(lblComment);
 Button btnactiv = new Button();
 btnactiv.ID = y.ToString();
 btnactiv.Text = "Dept " + dr_depts["code_dept"].ToString() + "(" + nbr + " )";
 commentCell.Controls.Add(btnactiv);
```

Comment: OMG thnx clever way to do it